# ActiveMQ "Classic" - Detecting Message Duplication

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, activemq-artemis

I am currently exploring de-duplication strategies within ActiveMQ "Classic." ActiveMQ Artemis supports [duplicate detection](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/duplicate-detection.html), but I'm not sure about ActiveMQ "Classic."

**Is it possible to prevent a message from being placed on a queue if it currently exists on the queue in ActiveMQ "Classic"?**

Messages which are no longer on the queue and have been so in the past will be allowed back on the queue.

The underlying capability I am trying to achieve is flow control in which multiple messages of the same value are not placed on the queue as to remove duplicate processing.

Based on the documentation, I have tried using the message property defined `_AMQ_DUPL_ID`, but I am still experiencing duplication. I suspect this may not be supported in ActiveMQ "Classic" and am unsure what alternative option is. I'm open to suggestions.

NOTE: The ActiveMQ instance being used is provided by [Amazon MQ](https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-mq/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you suspect, ActiveMQ "Classic" doesn't support automatic duplicate detection. This is only supported in ActiveMQ Artemis. That said, messages are not removed from the broker's duplicate ID cache when the message is consumed from the queue. This is because in most cases a duplicate sent after the message is consumed is still considered a duplicate.

You *may* be able to implement some kind of duplicate detection in a broker plugin, but I have no idea of Amazon MQ supports adding custom plugins. It's more likely that you'll have to implement duplicate detection in the clients themselves.